# Cannot update with 'sudo apt-get update' or update manager

Tags: installation, updates, update-manager

Beforehand, excuse me, I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, so I may be overlooking something quite obvious...

I have been attempting to install [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) *(It is an Internet anonymity software)* via the instructions for downloading the software through their deb repository, but every time I go to update with `sudo apt-get update`, I receive the following error messages:

```
 W: Failed to fetch
 http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release 
 Unable to find expected entry 'commercial/source/Sources' in Release
 file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

 W: Failed to fetch
 http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release 
 Unable to find expected entry 'commercial/source/Sources' in Release
 file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

 W: Failed to fetch
 http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release 
 Unable to find expected entry 'commercial/source/Sources' in Release
 file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
 ones used instead.
```

I also receive the same message from update manager... What exactly is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Those mirror.picosecond.org links seems unrelated to the Tor instructions on their website.
Please open the /etc/apt/sources.list file and post here any row containing mirror.picosecond.org.

```
gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Probably you have activated a "commercial" section which does not exists in that repository. In that case, remove that line.
For example, comment it by adding a # at the beginning of the line:

```
#deb http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu precise commercial
```

Comment: Now it sounds like a reply ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way if you messed up your `sources.list` file. Go to this little utility: [Debian Sources List Generator](http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/).

Take a backup of your current `sources.list` file and put your new generated contents there.

Do an `apt-get update` and you are done.